# How to cascade multiple look ahead adders

Tags: adder, carry-look-ahead

I know how we can prepare 4 bit [look-ahead carry adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Carry-lookahead_adder) (CLAs) to avoid delay involved in rippling of carries in [ripple carry adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Ripple-carry_adder). We calculate various signal in CLA as follows:

- Carry propagate signal $$P_i=A_i\oplus B_i$$
- Carry generate signal $$G_i=A_iB_i$$
- Sum $$S_i=P_i\oplus C_i$$
- Carry $$C_{i+1}=G_i+P_iC_i$$

For 4 bit CLAs, 
$$C_4=G_3 + P_3G_2 + P_3P_2G_1 + P_3P_2P_1G_0 + P_3P_2P_1P_0C_0 $$

As you can see, last term above requires 5 input AND gate. As we go one increasing bit count of input operands A and B, we will require AND gates with larger and larger inputs / fan ins. Some sources say, we can avoid this by cascading 4 bit CLAs to get 4n bit CLAs, for n=2,3,4,... However I dont fully get how we can prepare CLA for 4n bits as books / websites rarely explain it well. One good source I found is [this pdf](http://www.eng.ucy.ac.cy/theocharides/Courses/ECE210/Carrylookahead_supp4.pdf).
It gives following diagram:

**Diagram 1 (D1)**
[image]

I didnt get it fully from pdf also, but got some hints. So I tried to figure out the same on my own. I need confirmation of my understanding. Below is what I have thought and figured out.

> Consider this CLA block diagram:
>
> **Diagram 2 (D2)**
>
> [image]
>
> Considering above 4 bit CLA, I prepared block diagram of 16 bit CLAs as follows (please right click image and click "Open image in new tab" in Chrome browser for zooming in):
>
> **Diagram 3 (D3)**
>
> [image]
>
> I prepared D3 myself and hence I need confirmation for correctness of explanation I have given in below numbered points, more importantly points 4, 7 and 8:
>
> 1. In D2, all things which are done outside of carry look ahead block (green and blue gates) is done inside PFAs blocks of D1. (You may have to read the pdf to confirm this.)
> 2. All boxes in top most row of D3 corresponds to green gates in D2. Blue XOR gates calculating sums Si in D2 are not shown / ignored in D3. In D2, carry lookahead block is shown to have P and C as output. In D3, I have shown only C as output of carry lookahead block (CLA blocks in 2nd and 3rd rows), as D3 ignores sums.
> 3. Since PFAs in D1 also contains logic to calculate sum, they also have carry input from Level 1 CLs. This is not the case with blocks in top most row of D3 as they do not contain the logic to do sum, blue XORs in D2, but contains only logic of green gates of D2.
> 4. Following naming in D1 is incorrect:
>      [image]
>      It should have been:
>      [image]
> 5. The red colored carry signals in D3 are not generated or are ignored as we dont want rippling carries. Instead green colored carry signals are produced (as per look ahead logic) and used.
> 6. Red colored P and G signals in D3 CLA 2 are also unused / ignored
> 7. Green colored C15 output of D3 CLA 2 is final carry. It is produced by same logic as carry logic specified above: $$C_{15}=G_{12,15}+P_{12,15}G_{8,11}+P_{12,15}P_{8,11}G_{4,7}+P_{12,15}P_{8,11}P_{4,7}G_{0,3}+P_{12,15}P_{8,11}P_{4,7}P_{0,3}C_0$$
> 8. Does OC block in D1 represent above equation only? (I dont think so because there is no such explicit block in D3 accepting G(0,15) and P(0,15) as input.) (You may have to read pdf to confiem this.)
> 9. In D1 and D3, $$G_{x,x+3}=C_{x+3}$$ and $$P_{x,x+3}=P_{x+3}P_{x+2}P_{x+1}P_{x}$$
>      that is, they dont follow standard equations of Pi and Gi (repeated below): $$P_i=A_i\oplus B_i$$ $$G_i=A_iB_i$$

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I have an observation and a suggestion.  The observation is that the carry out of an addition is dependent on *every bit* going into the adder; look-ahead either needs to be in chunks like this (and thus still needs to ripple through to some extent) or it needs a tremendous amount of logic.  This is why pipelined adders are a thing.  The suggestion is that it looks to me like you're doing good work, and perhaps you should *code this up* in Verilog or VHDL, whichever you're most comfortable with, and see how it works.

Comment: sorry to sound not good, but am computer science major and struggling with electronics background...I never learnt Verilog or VHDL, also never heard of pipelined adders. So want help from someone more knowledge in electronics. We have digital logic as only electronics related subject in syllabus which contains topics of ripple adders and look ahead adder. In one of previous year exams, question related to cascading carry lookahead adders was asked. Our instructor & text book did not discuss cascading lookahead adders. So need someone helps in my above understanding.